# Is there any algorithm for turning simple Haxe code into C/C++ code files?

Tags: c++, c, haxe, hxcpp

I have simple Haxe app like

```
class Main
{
    public static function main()
    {
        trace("hello world");
    }
}
```

I know how to compile such app for windows (not as SWF but as app from pure C\C++ )(and you can see how [here](http://blog.touchmypixel.com/2009/04/our-possible-haxe-c-plans/) but be worned thay use hxcpp\0,4 ) The problem is - I do not want to compile app for Windows Vista or 7 or XP I want to get PURE C\C++ code (better in one place as one project) for for example compiling that code on windows mobile or where ever I want to.

So is there any algorithm for turning simple Haxe code into C/C++ code files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAICT `hxcpp` does generate C++ code which uses a platform specific library(Neko). the output is not windows specific.